# Automatically adding file locations (pictures) to an Access database via PowerShell or Python

Tags: python, ms-access, powershell, automation, batch-processing

I have a Microsoft Access database, and pictures that have file names matching entries in the database (though part of the file name is irrelevant).  I need to read the file names and insert links to them into the database attached to their correct entries.  I've been playing around with PowerShell and Python for a while, but have little experience with Access and can't find a lot of documentation on the subject.  So my questions are:

1. Am I better off using PowerShell, Python, or something else for this project?  I just happen to have experience with those two languages so they're my preferred jumping off point.
2. I imagine this will take a good amount of work and I don't mind getting my hands dirty/doing a lot of research, but after looking around I can't seem to find a good place to get started.  Are there any specific commands, documentation, functions, etc. that could give me a jumpstart on this project?

Thanks!

EDIT: Thanks to @ako for bringing up a good point and something I was concerned about.  Putting the photos in the DB itself is likely a bad idea, so I'd like to instead host them elsewhere then automatically have links to the files generated in the DB based on the file names and matching DB entries.

Comment: Are you sure you want to store images in the actual database? You could run into size issues given Access' limited size. There is nothing stopping you from using external images in a report, if that is what your ultimate goal is. Beyond that, you may want to work with VBA which is native to, if cumbersome, Access.

Comment: @ako Great point, and I'd actually been thinking about that myself.  I wasn't aware it had a limited size but I was concerned about possible speed/backup size issues.  I would be interested in perhaps then hosting the images on a server, and having a field in the database with a link to those images.

Comment: You can have a column storing file paths and use that path to update the image source of an image frame in the report.